# Can node-oracledb invoke pl/sql stored procedure having custom table type as a parameter?

Tags: node.js, stored-procedures, plsql, node-oracledb

Currently, I'm trying to invoke a PL/SQL stored procedure (having custom table type as a parameter) using node-oracledb.

Declaration of custom variable in PL/SQL:

```
TYPE 'ARR_USERNAME' as table of varchar2(32767);
```

Parameter declaration of ARR_USERNAME:

```
username IN arr_username
```

Here, I'm trying to invoke the procedure:

```
const result = await connection.execute(
  `BEGIN
    PROC_NAME(:var_1, :username, :details);
  END;`, {
    var_1: { type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: 0 },
    username: { type: oracledb.VARCHAR2, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
      val: ['node', 'git', 'wow'] },
    details: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT },
  },
);
```

After running the code, I get following output:

```
[Error: ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROC_NAME'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored] {
  errorNum: 6550,
  offset: 14
}
```

Above, I tried to pass an array, but it's not working.

I can't change the stored procedure.

So, I have to call the stored procedure with the expected parameter type.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#plsqlcollections).  If you update your question with a runnable example, it would be easier for people to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A working example without node.js would be helpful. A dummy procedure, the actual type definition, how you call it etc.